# Create Project in Visual Studio 2015 with Entity Framework 5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-5

I'm using VS 2015 and need to create a new project but I can't find how to use a new project template with an older version of Entity Framework.

I need to use EF 5.0 and "new Project" in VS 2015 adds reference of EF 6 with all the login and other stuff.

Tired to search in the web but I still don't know how to do this.

Comment: Where is my 'Hi' at the beginning :?

Comment: First add EF 5 to your project by NuGet. (Make sure EF6 is not referenced). Then add a new model. For the options creating an edmx you'll get the question which EF version you want to use. Code-first from database isn't supported with EF5.

Comment: Thanks. I Understand that. But i'm getting errors like "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Isn't possible to create a project with .Net framework 4.5 and EF 5 from start? (with templates like MVC Web Project). I will have to do from scratch?

Comment: That's a different question that needs more details about the project history and current structure.